# Parsing PostgreSQL CSV Log

Tags: c#, postgresql

I am working an a section of application which needs to Parse CSV Logs generated by PostgreSql server.

- The Logs are stored C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\data\pg_log
- The Server version in 9.0.4
- The application is developed in C Sharp

  - The basic utility after Parse the Log is to show contents in a DataGridView.
  - There are other filter options like to view log contents for a particular range of Time for a Day.

**However the main problem that is, the Log format is not readable**

> It was first tested with A Fast CSV Reader

- [Parsing CSV files in C#, with header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081418/parsing-csv-files-in-c-sharp)
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx

> Then we made a custom utility using String.Split method with the usual Foreach loop going through the array

A Sample Log data line

> 2012-03-21 11:59:20.640 IST,"postgres","stock_apals",3276,"localhost:1639",4f697540.ccc,10,"idle",2012-03-21 11:59:20 IST,2/163,0,LOG,00000,"statement: SELECT id,pdate,itemname,qty from stock_apals order by pdate,id",,,,,,,,"exec_simple_query, .\src\backend\tcop\postgres.c:900",""

As you can see the columns in the Log are comma separated , But however individual values 
are not Quote Enclosed.

For instance the 1st,4rth,6th .. columns

**Is there a utility or  a Regex that can find malformed columns and place quotes**

*This is especially with respect to performace, becuase these Logs are very long and
new ones are made almost every hour*

I just want to update the columns and use the FastCSVReader to parse it.

Thanks for any advice and help

Comment: Doesn't FastCSVReader support mixed quoted/unquoted values?

Comment: what happens wrong is when it reaches the column where sql statement is place. it also has commas set for table columns. The log line is a mix bunch of quote-enclosed and non-quote-enclosed column. is there is a regex or utility to convert the non-quoted column to quoted column

Comment: on CSVReader page it highlights "This reader supports fields spanning multiple lines. The only restriction is that they must be quoted, otherwise it would not be possible to distinguish between malformed data and multi-line values."

Comment: Could you please provide some reasonable amount of log (including header) on http://pastebin.com/ for example, so I can test it in my own CVS parser.

Comment: here is a sample http://pastebin.com/uwfmRdU7

Comment: Thanks, unfortunatelly while my parser support mixed quoted columns, it does not support multiline values yet. I will work to fix that and will let you know then I will be able to parse your data.

Comment: is your parser available for sharing. maybe i can help update it to parse multiline values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated my csv parser, so it's now able to parse you data (at least provided in example). Below is exampe console app which is parsing your data saved in `multiline_quotes.txt` file. Project source can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/pabdulin/gorgon/src) (you can download a [ZIP](https://bitbucket.org/pabdulin/gorgon/get/219beac4a03c.zip)). You need either `Gorgon.Parsing` or `Gorgon.Parsing.Net35` (in case you can't use .NET 4.0).

Actually I was able to achive same result using [Fast CSV Reader](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader). You just used it some wrong way in the first place.

```
namespace So9817628
{
    using System.Data;
    using System.Text;
    using Gorgon.Parsing.Csv;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // prepare
            CsvParserSettings s = new CsvParserSettings();
            s.CodePage = Encoding.Default;
            s.ContainsHeader = false;
            s.SplitString = ",";
            s.EscapeString = "\"\"";
            s.ContainsQuotes = true;
            s.ContainsMultilineValues = true;
            // uncomment below if you don't want escape quotes ("") to be replaced with single quote
            //s.ReplaceEscapeString = false;

            CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(s);

            DataTable dt = parser.ParseToDataTableSequential("multiline_quotes.txt");

            dt.WriteXml("parsed.xml");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i have tested it on a sample and forwarded it for a full application test.