# Convert a Text File into a CSV File with C#

Tags: c#, arrays, csv

I have a txt file that is Tab Delimited, like this:

```
Well       Name       Detector      Task    Quantity
1          try1       Cam1          UNKN    0
2          try2       Cam1          UNKN    0
3          try3       Cam3          STND    1000
4          try4       Cam5          UNKN    0
5          try5       Cam6          UNKN    0
6          try6       Cam6          UNKN    0
....
92         try92      Cam4          STND    100
```

I need to output a CSV file from this TXT file.
In the outputted CSV file I need to change the delimiter from Tab to semi-colon and I only need the first two columns.

I put the text file in an array with:

```
string [] source....
```

also to skip some header lines I don't need,

But now I'm stuck at how to go on.

I know about StreamReader and StreamWriter but I don't know how to use them to accomplish my task.

Any help would be kindly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you show us what you've done so far so we can help you figure out what you're getting wrong?

Comment: As I said, I'm stuck after the creation of the array...

Comment: Step 1: parse CSV: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081418/parsing-csv-files-in-c-sharp. Step 2: create text file using StreamWriter or something else.

Comment: Code is for .NET 2.0 and I'm using 4.0. Could you post some sample code please?

Comment: ah, that is a huge difference. what about trying to convert it up? or you want us to do that for you?

Comment: @user1776401: Really, don't be lazy. Research, try something, think, *develop*!

Comment: I don't know how to change the delimiter and how to retrieve only the first two columns. The best would be some sample code I could also use to learn.

Comment: I'm not lazy at all. I've been trying all day to do it. And i don't want anyone to do something in my place...but...if this is the best advice i can get here...I could get it alone without posting anything. Post would be helpful to others, no some useless comment, as I've been searching the web for some hint but didn't find any.

Comment: @user1776401 We just need more information than 'how do I do this?'  You didn't even give us a full line of code.  You told us what classes you have used.  Is `source` just an initialized array? Is it full of the lines of text?  Are you having trouble writing the file? Are you having trouble skipping lines? Splitting lines?  Do you see what the problem is?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hope this gives you the idea, so try to understand each part.

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(YOUR INPUT FILE);

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    var temp = line.Split('\t');
    builder.AppendLine(string.Join(";", temp[0], temp[1]));
    //builder.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}; {1}", temp[0], temp[1]));
}

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(YOUR OUTPUT FILE, builder.ToString());
```

- `File.ReadAllLines`: Read all lines of a file into a `string[]`
- `File.WriteAllText`: Write a string into a file.
- [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx): This class represents a string-like object.
- `AppendLine`: Adds a string line to the `StringBuilder` instance.
- `string.Format`: Replaces each format item in a specified string with the text equivalent of a corresponding object's value. [More](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)

Comment: Then the key would be not to read the text file in an array, but in a list. I need to better understand the line that does the job: "builder.AppendLine...". About {1}...What does it do?

Comment: @user1776401 you can read it into an array.

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel. Parsing CSV files yourself may not be needed.

Comment: @L-Three if you post your solution it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hossein Narimani Rad, really...thank you! Reading some code is always the best way to learn, IMO. Could you post the way to do it reading the txt in an array?

Comment: @user1776401 I edit my post, I'm using a `sting[]`.