# Having trouble with parsing a CSV file in ASP

Tags: parsing, csv, asp-classic, vbscript

I have a CSV file of products that needs to be uploaded to the sites database.
The CSV is a normal comma delimited file, but the issue I am having is that some of the fields have a comma in the text. Most fields that have the comma in the text are surrounded by quotes so I assume that could be used some how. Below is the current code I have:

```
set objFile = server.CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set objFileTextStream = objFile.OpenTextFile(file)

'skip first line as those are headers
objFileTextStream.skipLine 

Do While objFileTextStream.AtEndOfStream <> True 

strLine = objFileTextStream.ReadLine

strLinePart = split(strLine,",") 

'Will have code to insert data in to the database here

Loop 

objFileTextStream.Close
Set objFileTextStream = Nothing
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: You could try treating it as a database rather than using Scripting.FileSystemObject.  One thing to be careful of though, make sure there are no invisible characters (spaces, line breaks) at the end of your file.  See this link and scroll down to "you can also open a text file.."

Answer (score 4):

The best way to use .CSV files is via the ADO text drivers ([start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx)). They will work even for more complex data (e.g. embedded line feeds, UTF-8, strange separators or line endings).

Importing .CSV tables into your DBMS can then be done by executing SQL statements ("SELECT/INSERT INTO ... IN ", "LOAD DATA INFILE ..." or whatever your DBMS supports) instead of writing loops.

But: "If [only] most fields that have the comma in the text are surrounded by quotes", you are in trouble. Even a 'roll your own' parser lives under the law "garbage in, garbage out". If you Split() on "," and get more than the expected elements only a (super) human may be able to assign the parts to the correct columns.

**Update wrt comments:**

The bad row

```
a,b,c,...
```

can mean:

```
"a,b","c",...
```

**or**

```
"a","b,c",...
```

A human, a parser, or a RegExp would need very specific additional information to decide which alternative is correct.

If you can't force your data source to deliver standard conforming .CSV, you should separate the (sub)task "transform garbage to 'real' .CSV" into a stand-alone process with its own development procedure and tests. Then you can use more capable tools ([Perl's CSV module](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.32/lib/Text/CSV.pm), [some CSharp libraries/projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081418/parsing-csv-files-in-c-sharp), ...), and/or even involve a human to look at the critical cases.