# Calculate Hashsum of filed from CSV file

Tags: c#, csv, sha1

Input: I have `.csv` file with `n` columns in it. First row is a header. I need to calculate sum of one the fields in `.csv` file (for example it's called `"Value"`) and then calculate hashsum of this sum, using SHA1.

I see that SHA1 can work with string http://snipplr.com/view/70294/
But how canI combine that with data from `.csv` file? Could you please help me on that.

Comment: What is it you're having trouble with _exactly_? As you can see in the **Related** column, there are quite some [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081418/parsing-csv-files-in-c-sharp?rq=1)  about reading CSV files. You usually read this data as strings, which you can pass to the code you found.

Comment: Have troubles with combining both in one working code.

Comment: Then show what you've got.

Answer (score 1):

A basic way of doing it would be:

- Read the CSV File
- Sum the values
- Pass the `ToString` value to SHA-1

```
public static string GetSha1Sum()
{
     double sum = 0;
     using (CSVReader cr = new CSVReader(myfilename))
     {
         foreach (string[] line in cr)
         {
             //assuming your field is the first: 
             sum += Convert.ToDouble(line[0]);
         }
     }
     SHA1 sha1Hash= SHA1.Create();
     byte[] data = sha1Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sum.ToString()));
     string digest = HexDigest(data);
 }
```

The `HexDigest` helper is a function that format a byte array into hex string:

```
public static string HexDigest(byte[] data)
{
    StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        //format the bytes in hexadecimal
        sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
    }
    return sBuilder.ToString();
}
```

More information about the [CSVReader](https://code.google.com/p/csharp-csv-reader/)