# Regex to get all "cells" form csv file row

Tags: c#, .net, regex, csv

**This is not duplicate! I'm asking for solution with regex. I can't use external libraries**

I have csv file with [,] as separator and ["] as escape character.
I need regex to get all the "cells" from the row.

This row should be converted to:

```
This, Is, "Super Test", That, "Should, maybe work", Oh

1. This
2. Is
3. Super Test
4. That
5. Should, maybe work
6. Oh
```

I want to to be universal so I can't hardcode number of "cells".

Can you help me create regex for that?

What I tried?
I tried creating regex but failed.

P.S.
If you know other method that is nice or maybe faster I'd be happy to hear about it.

Comment: Use a [CsvParser](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper)

Comment: Perhaps... [csv parser c#](https://www.google.com/search?q=csv+parser+c%23&oq=csv+par&aqs=chrome.0.0l2j69i57j0l3.1712j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: You've forgotten to include what you've tried already.

Comment: check this answer on the "duplicate" question http://stackoverflow.com/a/9935529/2390075