# ASP.Net MVC Error: Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm uploading a .txt file using ASP.Net MVC. I used the codes from http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=323. When I'm uploading a .txt file which has more than 30,000 rows I'm getting this error: **Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.**

--

Table **TMPUPLOAD** columns:

vdate | time | ampm | empno

--

sample data of my **.txt file:**

08/01/12,05:09:09 AM,200441,,North Lobby1,358709,VERIFY_OK

08/01/12,05:09:09 AM,200441,,North Lobby1,358709,VERIFY_OK

08/22/12,12:13:36 PM,228079,Lim,Benedict Drew,South Lobby2,123903,VERIFY_OK

--

and the codes:

```
public ActionResult ChronologFiles()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ChronologFiles(HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload)
        {
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string line = string.Empty;
            int i = 0;

            //check we have a file
            if (FileUpload.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                //Workout our file path
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload.FileName);
                string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/UploadedFiles"), fileName);

                //Try and upload
                try
                {
                    FileUpload.SaveAs(path);
                    //Process the CSV file and capture the results to our DataTable place holder
                    dt = ProcessCSV(path);

                    //Process the DataTable and capture the results to our SQL Bulk copy
                    ViewData["Feedback"] = ProcessBulkCopy(dt);

                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, true))
                    {
                        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            string[] data = line.Split(',', ' ', '\n');
                            if (data.Length > 0)
                            {
                                if (i == 0)
                                {
                                    foreach (var item in data)
                                    {
                                        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn());
                                    }
                                    i++;
                                }
                                DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                                row.ItemArray = data;
                                dt.Rows.Add(row);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Catch errors
                    ViewData["Feedback"] = ex.Message;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Catch errors
                ViewData["Feedback"] = "Please select a file";
            }

            //Tidy up
            dt.Dispose();


            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ALEMSDB"].ConnectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                {
                    copy.ColumnMappings.Add(0, "vdate");
                    copy.ColumnMappings.Add(1, "time");
                    copy.ColumnMappings.Add(2, "ampm");
                    copy.ColumnMappings.Add(3, "empno");
                    copy.DestinationTableName = "TMPUPLOAD";
                    copy.WriteToServer(dt);
                }

                using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM TMPUPLOAD WHERE empno = ''", con))
                {

                    int rows = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    //rows number of record got inserted
                }

                using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO UPLOADING(vdate, [time], ampm, empno)
                                                            SELECT vdate, [time], ampm, empno
                                                            FROM TMPUPLOAD", con))
                {

                    int rows = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    //rows number of record got inserted
                }

                using (SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE UPLOADING
                                                            SET inout = 'I'
                                                            WHERE [time] BETWEEN '04:00:00' AND '11:59:59' OR [time] BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '16:00:00' 
                                                                OR [time] BETWEEN '18:00:00' AND '23:59:59' AND ampm = 'AM'", con))
                {

                    int rows = cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    //rows number of record got inserted
                }

                using (SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE UPLOADING
                                                            SET inout = 'O'
                                                            WHERE [time] BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '12:59:59' OR [time] BETWEEN '13:00:00' AND '17:59:59'
                                                                OR [time] BETWEEN '18:00:00' AND '23:59:59' AND ampm = 'PM'", con))
                {

                    int rows = cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    //rows number of record got inserted
                }
            }



            return View();
        }
```

I only need the 08/01/12,05:09:09 AM,200441 that's why I only have four columns in my table and I just really want to know why I am getting this error..
Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] data = line.Split(',', ' ', '\n');
```

this line of code will split

05:09:09 AM
North Lobby1

to 2 column due to the space.

Comment: Yes because I'm going to split the **05:09:09 AM** so that the 05:09:09 will insert to the time column and the AM will insert to the ampm column. After the empno has been inserted it should proceed to the next row and so on.. @ah_hau

Comment: add a counter to track which line of data is having invalid data. Maybe is data issues @cupcakecode

Comment: I noticed the rows(data). Please check the sample data of my .txt file above (I included it). Some rows have names and some have not. When I checked the database table the data from the .txt with no names were inserted but it stopped and give an error message: Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table. I have more than 30,000 rows in my txt file and only 200 rows were inserted. I really think because its the names. Do you know how can I solve this? Thanks.. @ah_hau

Comment: @cupcakecode, since you only interest about the 4 column in the line, why don't read that 4 only, fix your dt to create 4 column, and get data[0], data[1],data[2],data[3] to pump into the datatable

Answer (score 0):

So you are doing:

```
//Process the CSV file and capture the results to our DataTable place holder
dt = ProcessCSV(path);
```

Followed by:

```
if (i == 0)
{
    // Weren't the columns already added by the ProcessCSV method?
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn());
    }
    i++;
}
```

If I understand correctly, you already added the data to your DataTable in the ProcessCSV method. A DataTable will not allow you to add any columns if it already has data in it.

Parsing CSV usually requires more than just a split method because of different formatting requirements for certain fields. Rather than trying to reinvent the wheel for parsing CSV, you should use the [built-in parser described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081418/parsing-csv-files-in-c-sharp#20523165). Once you have the data into separate CSV fields, you can then do a split on your date field.

Comment: Thanks for noticing! I already deleted the dt = ProcessCSV(path). @NightOwl888