# top-k tuples retrieval in distributed database

Tags: c#

I would be grateful if anyone could help me by providing me the code snippet on how to connect multiple .csv files to a single project in C# so that i cam implement an algorithm on these files in order to retrieve overall top-k (k is the user input) records from these files after sorting and ranking data in each file.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does your data look like? What are you going to sort and rank from the data?

Comment: The data consists of various attributes like pressure, humidity,temp,speed etc. The data is taken from Shipboard Automated Meteorological Oceanographic System. The data is downloaded for three months and each file was in .nc format. I converted it to csv files. Now i need to connect these separate csv files to c# and implement an algorithm on this data. Each csv file consist of so many rows of data (readings of each day of a month)

Comment: [**Parsing CSV files in C#**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081418/parsing-csv-files-in-c-sharp)