# How to insert database what read four values in txt file?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I'm using c# MVC project.
I have a customer class and customer table.I have a Insert function with four parameter `name` , `surname` ,`phone`,`address`.I want to read .txt file line by line and split with "," and use this Insert function but I don't know how can create algorithm.

```
 static void AddCustomer(string Name, string Surname, string Phone, string Address)
    {
        using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
        {
            using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var customer = new Customer
                {
                    Name = Name,
                    Surname = Surname,
                    Phone = Phone,
                    Address = Address,
                };
                session.Save(customer);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }



            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string text = file.ReadToEnd();
                string[] lines = text.Split(',');
                for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
                {
                    //HOW CAN I USER ADDCUSTOMER()
                }  

                counter++;
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You've almost got it. Assuming `file` is a `StreamReader`, you can just split the current line on comma, and pass the separate parts to the `AddCustomer` method:

```
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    // Split the line on comma
    var lineParts = line.Split(',');

    string name = lineParts[0];
    string surname = lineParts[1];
    string phone = lineParts[2];
    string address = lineParts[3];

    AddCustomer(name, surname, phone, address);
}
```

Please note that this does no error checking at all (`lineParts[1]` will blow up if there's no comma in the given line) and that this is a bad way to parse CSV (if the data contains comma's, which addresses tend to do, it'll not work properly). Use a CSV parsing library.

See [Parsing CSV files in C#, with header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081418/parsing-csv-files-in-c-sharp) and plenty of other questions about CSV, where it is suggested that you use the [FileHelpers library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FileHelpers/). Your class that maps to and from the CSV file will look like this:

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
[IgnoreEmptyLines()]
public class MyProduct
{
    [FieldOrder(0)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [FieldOrder(1)]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [FieldOrder(2)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [FieldOrder(3)]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

And the code to read the file:

```
var engine = new FileHelperEngine<CustomerCsvRecord>();
CustomerCsvRecord[] customers = engine.ReadFile(fileName);

foreach (var customer in customers)
{
    AddCustomer(customer.Name, customer.Surname, customer.Phone, customer.Address);
}
```

Comment: +1:  I've always enjoyed reading your answers.  One thing though, can you not do something like this?  `var engine = new FileHelperEngine<CustomerCsvRecord>(); var customers = engine.ReadFile(fileName);` [MSDN reference](http://www.filehelpers.net/docs/html/T_FileHelpers_FileHelperEngine_1.htm).

Comment: Not a problem. :) Actually, the `var` is fine.  It's the cast I don't think is necessary.

Comment: @JohnH thanks, those comments make it worth the effort. ;) I have changed the code to use the generic `FileHelperEngine`, that indeed makes the code somewhat more readable.

Answer (score 0):

This will do your job.

```
        string fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("YOUR_FILE_PATH");

        //assumeing each customer record will be on separate line
        string[] lines = fileContent.Split(new string [] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            //assuming a single line content will be like this "name,surname,phone,address"
            string[] items = line.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            Customer cust = new Customer();
            cust.Name = items[0];
            cust.Surname = items[1];
            cust.Phone = items[2];
            cust.Address = items[3];

            //now use this 'cust' object
        }
```