# Regex split for comma and double quotes CSV format

Tags: c#, regex, csv

I am not really good in Regex.

The string:

```
"FF","asdadasd60","Report,License","502","5A1301","I-Web Report,License","50A1","PR02","02","5A11","REL","","","","A1170600","500008","FA10","5000001","","","","","000000000.000","","000000000.000","","000000000.000","","000000000.000","","00000000","00000000","",""
```

I have done this but remove the double quotes before. But the result for string `Report,License` and `I-Web Report,License` are splitted. This is wrong.

I want to split it into array by comma between double quotes not inside them.

Comment: I would do this manually. You know, `List<string>`, `for`-loop and `Substring`. It is more performant, I guess.

Comment: var values = Regex.Split(line, ",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a real csv parser instead of using string methods or regex. You could use the [`TextFieldParser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx) which is the only one available in the framework directly:

```
var allLineFields = new List<string[]>();
using (var parser = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(new StringReader(str)))
{
    parser.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };
    parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true; // <--- !!!
    string[] lineFields;
    while ((lineFields = parser.ReadFields()) != null)
    {
        allLineFields.Add(lineFields);
    }
}
```

You need to add a reference to the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` dll to your project.

There are other available: [Parsing CSV files in C#, with header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081418/parsing-csv-files-in-c-sharp)