# C# Read text file and print out in to a table

Tags: c#, file-io

I'm trying to read a text file and print out into a table.
I want the output to be this

[image]

But now I having different output

[image]

```
var column1 = new List<string>();
var column2 = new List<string>();
var column3 = new List<string>();

using (var rd = new StreamReader(@"C:\test.txt"))
{
    while (!rd.EndOfStream)
    {
          var splits = rd.ReadLine().Split(';');
          column1.Add(splits[0]);
          column2.Add(splits[1]);
          column3.Add(splits[2]);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Date/Time \t Movie \t Seat");
foreach (var element in column1) Console.WriteLine(element); 
foreach (var element in column2) Console.WriteLine(element);
foreach (var element in column3) Console.WriteLine(element);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *Linq* to construct a convenient structure (e.g. `List<String[]>`) and then print out all the data wanted:

```
List<String[]> data = File
  .ReadLines(@"C:\test.txt")
 //.Skip(1) // <- uncomment this to skip caption if the csv has it
  .Select(line => line.Split(';').Take(3).ToArray()) // 3 items only
  .ToList();

// Table output (wanted one):
String report = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
  data.Select(items => String.Join("\t", items)));   

Console.WriteLine(report);

// Column after column output (actual one)
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, data.Select(item => item[0])));
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, data.Select(item => item[1])));
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, data.Select(item => item[2])));
```

**EDIT**: if you want to *choose the movie*, *buy the ticket* etc. elaborate the structure:

```
  // Create a custom class where implement your logic 
  public class MovieRecord {
    private Date m_Start;
    private String m_Name;
    private int m_Seats;

    ... 
    public MovieRecord(DateTime start, String name, int seats) {
      ...
      m_Seats = seats;
      ...
    }
    ...

    public String ToString() {
      return String.Join("\t", m_Start, m_Name, m_Seats);
    }

    public void Buy() {...}
    ...
  }
```

And then convert to *conventinal structure*:

```
  List<MovieRecord> data = File
    .ReadLines(@"C:\test.txt")
    //.Skip(1) // <- uncomment this to skip caption if the csv has it
    .Select(line => {
       String items[] = line.Split(';'); 
       return new MovieRecord(
         DateTime.ParseExact(items[0], "PutActualFormat", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 
         items[1], 
         int.Parse(items[2]));
    }
    .ToList();
```

And the table output will be

```
  Console.Write(String.Join(Envrironment.NewLine, data));
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I've missed `.ToArray()` when creating a line representation: `line => line.Split(';').Take(3).ToArray()` -  split, take 3 items and return an array

Comment: thanks. if i want to choose the movie and when i buy the ticket how do i reduce the int the 3rd column?

Comment: @user3612950: you have to construct a *convenient structure* for your task(s). See my edit.

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/pS3pyMLy)  this is the class for booking ticket. did I do it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Console.WriteLine` if you want to add a "column". You should also use a single `List<string[]>` instead of multiple `List<string>`.

```
List<string[]> allLineFields = new List<string[]>();
using (var rd = new StreamReader(@"C:\test.txt"))
{
    while (!rd.EndOfStream)
    {
        var splits = rd.ReadLine().Split(';');
        allLineFields.Add(splits);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Date/Time \t Movie \t Seat");
foreach(string[] line in allLineFields)
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\t", line));
```

In general you should use a real csv parser if you want to parse a csv-file, not string methods or regex.

You could use the `TextFieldParser` which is the only one available in the framework directly:

```
var allLineFields = new List<string[]>();
using (var parser = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(@"C:\test.txt"))
{
    parser.Delimiters = new string[] { ";" };
    parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = false; // very useful 
    string[] lineFields;
    while ((lineFields = parser.ReadFields()) != null)
    {
        allLineFields.Add(lineFields);
    }
}
```

You need to add a reference to the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` dll to your project.

There are other available: [Parsing CSV files in C#, with header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081418/parsing-csv-files-in-c-sharp)

Comment: how to i choose the movie and when i buy the ticket how do i reduce the int in the file?

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to solve this in a more Object-Orientated manner, which might make it a bit easier for you to work with:

You can declare a simple class to represent a movie seat:

```
class MovieSeat
{
    public readonly string Date, Name, Number;

    public MovieSeat(string source)
    {
        string[] data = source.Split(';');
        Date = data[0];
        Name = data[1];
        Number = data[2];
    }
}
```

And then you can read in and print out the data in a few lines of code:

```
// Read in the text file and create a new MovieSeat object for each line in the file.
// Iterate over all MovieSeat objets and print them to console.
foreach(var seat in File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\test.txt").Select(x => new MovieSeat(x)))
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\t", seat.Date, seat.Name, seat.Number));
```