# Need RegEx or some other way for separating quoted tokens containing escaped quotes

Tags: c#, regex, quotes

Basically, my task is to parse this command line:

```
-p "This is a string ""with quotes""" d:\1.txt "d:\some folder\1.out"
```

What I need is to split this string into:

1. -p
2. This is a string "with quotes"
3. d:\1.txt
4. d:\some folder\1.out

I searched (yes, I really did), but all examples I found either had not included escaped quotes or used \" for escape symbol.

Comment: Even if they did not work for you, please share what you have tried.

Comment: `or used \" for escape symbol.` So you are basically using `"` to escape `"`, so it shouldn't be *that hard* to adapt.

Comment: I used this one: ("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*") and this one ((?<![\\])['"])((?:.(?!(?<![\\])\1))*.?) and this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a regex (if you insist on not using a parser as Tim Schmelter's answer suggested), something like this should work (it matches the given string, but I can't guarantee it's completely bullet-proof):

```
((?:"(?:[^"]|"")*")|\S+)
```

Breaking it down, you are grouping either:

- A quote `"` followed by not a quote `^"` or two quotes `""`, followed by a quote `"`
- A bunch (one or more) of non-space characters `\S`

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/pA8kG7/1) to play around with it.

Comment: That works! I'll have to test it but it appears I've found what I looked for.

Comment: Or `"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"|\S+` is even better.

Answer (score 5):

I would use a real csv-parser instead, for example the only one available in .NET:

```
string str = "-p \"This is a string \"\"with quotes\"\"\" d:\\1.txt \"d:\\some folder\\1.out\"";
var allLineFields = new List<string[]>();
using (var parser = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(new StringReader(str)))
{
    parser.Delimiters = new string[] { " " };
    parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true; // <--- !!!
    string[] lineFields;
    while ((lineFields = parser.ReadFields()) != null)
    {
        allLineFields.Add(lineFields);
    }
}
```

With your sample string the list contains a single `string[]` with your four tokens:

```
-p
This is a string "with quotes"
d:\1.txt
d:\some folder\1.out
```

Comment: Is there any way I can get by without Microsoft.VisualBasic?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081418/parsing-csv-files-in-c-sharp) you will find alternatives like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) or [this](http://www.filehelpers.net/). But they are not better than the .NET parser

Answer (score 0):

A handwritten version:

```
private static string[] ParseArguments(string text)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text)) return new string[0];
    var entries = new List<string>(8);
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(64);
    var inString  = false;
    var l = text.Length;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        var c = text[i];
        if (inString)
        {
            if (c == '"')
            {
                if (i != l - 1 && text[i + 1] == '"')
                {
                    stringBuilder.Append(c);
                    i++;
                }
                else inString = false;
            }
            else stringBuilder.Append(c);
        }
        else if (c == '"') inString = true;
        else if (char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
        {
            if (stringBuilder.Length == 0) continue;
            entries.Add(stringBuilder.ToString());
            stringBuilder.Length = 0;
        }
        else stringBuilder.Append(c);
    }
    if (stringBuilder.Length != 0) entries.Add(stringBuilder.ToString());
    return entries.ToArray();
}
```