# Match the number of commas in CSV line that are not between quotation marks with C#

Tags: c#, regex, csv, regex-lookarounds

I have a CSV line and I need to count the number of columns in the line.

Some of the column values contains comma (in this case the value will be surround with quotation marks)

**I need a Regex that will match only commas that are not surrounded with quotation marks.**

For example:

```
a,b,c
```

will match 2 commas

and The line:

```
a,"b,c",d,"e,f"
```

will match 3 commas

Thanks,

Nadav.

Comment: Don't forget `a,"b,""c, d""",e`

Comment: Could you use an existing CSV parser instead? See some of the examples in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081418/parsing-csv-files-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

I doubt if a *complex* regular expression will be better than an *easy* loop:

```
private static int CountCommas(String source, Char separator = ',') {
  int result = 0;
  Boolean inQuotation = false;

  foreach (Char c in source)
    if (c == '"')
      inQuotation = !inQuotation;
    else if ((c == separator) && !inQuotation)
      result += 1;

  return result;
}
```

Test

```
  // 3
  Console.Write(CountCommas("a, \"b,c\", d, \"e,f\""));
```

Comment: Dimitry, thanks for your answer.you are probably right, currently I have a simple loop in my code. I want to see what people can offer (also as part of a learning process)

Comment: @NadavWolfin: You do not want a regex for this. There is a direct duplicate of your question that lists some regexps that work with some strings, but once you have longer strings, your app might freeze, or will be very slow. Use a CSV parser, or Dmitry's suggestion.