# how to split data in one column which holds a string and Datetime data in a new column in the Csv file?

Tags: c#

within my Csv File i have a column which holds a string and a datetime type. i would like to separate these data in two columns, one column which holds the string and one which holds the date but converts the datetime type as a string too.

After doing some research i noticed that i could use the string.split function which will add a comma after the three character which are TIP and then push the date in a new column. however i do not know to code this process

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(currentDirectory);
        var fileName = Path.Combine(directory.FullName, "Climate 02_08_2016.csv");
        var fileContents = ReadFile(fileName);
        string[] fileLines = fileContents.Split(new char[] { 'r', 'n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (var line in fileLines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);

        }





    }

            public static string ReadFile(string fileName)
         {
             var column5 = new List<string>();
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
               {



                 while (reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var splits = reader.ReadLine().Split(';');
                    column5.Add(splits[4]);
                }

                 return reader.ReadToEnd();
               }


        }



    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide a row or two of sample data from your CSV?

Comment: BinLocation:  TUI 01/01/20.  This is the csv column name and the row data.

Comment: Don't use string splitting as surrogate CSV parsing. [Use a library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081418/parsing-csv-files-in-c-with-header).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.Split` splits a string into array of strings based on a delimiter specified. [MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx).

You could use `String.Replace` method to replace space with a comma.

```
var result = yourStringVar.Replace(' ', ',')
```

Here is the full code (slightly simplified).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Climate 02_08_2016.csv");
        var fileContents = ReadFile(filePath);
        foreach (var line in fileContents)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static IList<string> ReadFile(string fileName)
    {
        var results = new List<string>();

        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            // Skip the line with column names
            if (i == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // Replace space with a comma
            var replace = lines[i].Replace(' ', ',');

            results.Add(replace);
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

I get following output:

```
TUI,01/01/20
Press any key to exit...
```

Please let me know if this is enough for you to implement your own solution.

Comment: Thank you this is taking me towards the solution, however instead of splitting them by space id like to split them with a comma in between which will then separate them and place them in two different column. please let me know if you have any idea.