# Make a new object from csv file using LINQ c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a csv file

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2011-09-23,24.90,25.15,24.69,25.06,64768100,25.06
2011-09-22,25.30,25.65,24.60,25.06,96278300,25.06
...
```

and i have a class `StockQuote` with fields
`Date,open,high...`
How can i make a list of `StockQuote` object from csv file using **linq**?

I m trying something like this:`

```
 stirng[] Data = parser.ReadFields();  
     var query = from d in Data  
    where !String.IsNullorWhiteSpace(d)  
    let data=d.Split(',')  
    select new StockQuote()  
    {  
    Date=data[0],  Open=double.Parse(data [ 1 ] ),
    ...
```

`

Comment: Why using LINQ? cos its a great buzz word? you know theres a csv parser available right?

Comment: Please add your code into the question as text.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what's wrong what the code you are trying

Comment: Wasn't it harder to take a picture than copy and paste the text?

Comment: the problem is that i dont get a new StockQuote object.I want every row from a file to be a SQ object.

Comment: If Date is defined as a string (as opposed to a DateTime) then this should work and should create a new StockQuote object for every row.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this..

```
var yourData = File.ReadAllLines("yourFile.csv")
                   .Skip(1)
                   .Select(x => x.Split(','))
                   .Select(x => new
                                {
                                    Date= x[0],
                                    Open = double.Parse(x[1]),
                                    High = double.Parse(x[2]),
                                    Low = double.Parse(x[3]),
                                    Close = double.Parse(x[4]),
                                    Volume = double.Parse(x[5]),
                                    AdjClose = double.Parse(x[6])
                                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using Linq, Regex or the like for CSV parsing. For CSV parsing, use a CSV Parser.
Linq and Regex will work exactly *until* you run into a escaped control character, multiline fields or something of the sort. Then they will plain break. And propably be unfixable.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question :
[Parsing CSV files in C#, with header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081418/parsing-csv-files-in-c-with-header)

The answer mentionning .Net integrated CSV parser seems fine.
And no, you don't need Linq for this.