# Skip reading the first line of the csv file

Tags: c#, csv

I am a beginner in programming,It's really difficult for me to analyze and debug how to skip reading the first line of the csv file. I need some help.
I need my id to fill my combobox in my form that contains all 
Id's.In order to not include the header in browsing and 
displaying.I need to skip the first line.

```
    public bool ReadEntrie(int id, ref string name, ref string lastname, ref 
    string phone, ref string mail, ref string website)
    {
        int count = 0;
        CreateConfigFile();
        try
        {
            fs = new FileStream(data_path, FileMode.Open);
            sr = new StreamReader(fs);
            string temp = "";
            bool cond = true;
            while (cond == true)
            {
                if ((temp = sr.ReadLine()) == null)
                {
                    sr.Close();
                    fs.Close();
                    cond = false;
                    if (count == 0)
                        return false;
                }
                if (count == id)
                {
                    string[] stringSplit = temp.Split(',');
                    int _maxIndex = stringSplit.Length;
                    name = stringSplit[0].Trim('"');
                    lastname = stringSplit[1].Trim('"');
                    phone = stringSplit[2].Trim('"');
                    mail = stringSplit[3].Trim('"');
                    website = stringSplit[4].Trim('"');
                }
                count++;
            }
            sr.Close();
            fs.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could use `var line = File.ReadLines(fileName).Skip(id).FirstOrDefault()` instead of bothering with the streams to get the one line you want.  If id > 0 then you'd always skip the first row, but if id could be 0 then you'd just do `Skip(id + 1)` instead.

Comment: There are few bugs: 1) In the block `if` where you set `cond` to false, you are closing `sr` and `fs`, but when the count is not `0` you close it again when you end `while` loop. I guess that it will cause exception. 2) The same case as previous, but it will fail earlier in the next `if` statement. When the `temp` is `null` and with a lot of bad luck the `count` equals `id` then you are trying to access `null.Split(',');` but it causes exception. I would recomend to extend `if (count == 0) return false;` with `else return true;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To skip the first line, just replace the line:

```
if (count == id)
```

with

```
if (count > 0 && count == id)
```

MORE THOUGHTS ON YOUR APPROACH

Because you used the `ref` keyword, each line you read will override the previous values you stored in the parameters. A better way to do this is to create a class to hold all the properties of interest. Then, for each line you read, package an instance of the class and add it to a list. You method signature (even the return type) will change eventually.

From your code, the class will look like this:

```
public class DataModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Phone{ get; set; }
    public string Mail { get; set; }
    public string Website{ get; set; }
}
```

Then your method will be like this:

```
public IList<DataModel> ReadEntrie(int id, string data_path)
{
    int count = 0;
    CreateConfigFile();
    var fs = new FileStream(data_path, FileMode.Open);
    var sr = new StreamReader(fs);
    try
    {
        var list = new List<DataModel>();
        string temp = "";
        bool cond = true;
        while (cond == true)
        {
            if ((temp = sr.ReadLine()) == null)
            {
                cond = false;
                if (count == 0)
                    throw new Exception("Failed");
            }
            if (count > 0 && count == id)
            {
                string[] stringSplit = temp.Split(',');
                var item = new DataModel();
                item.Name = stringSplit[0].Trim('"');
                item.LastName = stringSplit[1].Trim('"');
                item.Phone = stringSplit[2].Trim('"');
                item.Mail = stringSplit[3].Trim('"');
                item.Website = stringSplit[4].Trim('"');
                // add item to list
                list.Add(item);
            }
            count++;
        }
        return list;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw; // or do whatever you wish
    }
    finally
    {
        sr.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the the quick response.I will try it.

Comment: Test run was done. It works but new problem start shinning a logic error. I cannot add new line for the new data, It always overwriting the 2nd line.

Comment: @Sam Your problem is due to your use of `ref`; every time your code runs, it overrides the previous data set. I will update my answer to show you a better way to go about it.

Comment: I try your method above. But I encountered an error: Inconsistent accessiblity: return type 'IList<csvfile.DataModel>' is less accessible than method 'csvfile.ReadEntrie(int, string)'

Comment: I used two class. To make a whole picture of my code processes. My research about ADD,UPDATE,EDIT,DELETE in the csv file, I refer to this link. And I debug for my specific used. I feel difficulties from this flow of codes..https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/27a98772-2dc6-4197-9f75-6cc119d4a88a/how-to-edit-a-line-from-a-text-file-using-c?forum=Vsexpressvcs

Comment: If you need help on doing CRUD operations on CSV files, you may want to ask a new question. My last comment solves the issue you reported: just mark the class `DataModel` as `public`.

Answer (score 1):

@Somadina's answer is correct, but I would suggest a better alternative. You could use a CSV file parser library such as [CSV Helpers](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper).

You can get the library from Nuget or Git. Nuget command would be:

```
Install-Package CsvHelper
```

Declare the following namespaces:

```
using CsvHelper;
using CsvHelper.Configuration;
```

Here's how simple your code looks when you use such a library:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var csv = new CsvReader(File.OpenText("Path_to_your_csv_file"));
        csv.Configuration.IgnoreHeaderWhiteSpace = true;
        csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<MyCustomObjectMap>();
        var myCustomObjects = csv.GetRecords<MyCustomObject>();

        foreach (var item in myCustomObjects.ToList())
        {
            // Apply your application logic here.
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        }
    }
}

public class MyCustomObject
{
    // Note: You may want to use a type converter to convert the ID to an integer.
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Mail { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name.ToString();
    }
}

public sealed class MyCustomObjectMap : CsvClassMap<MyCustomObject>
{
    public MyCustomObjectMap()
    {
        // In the name method, you provide the header text - i.e. the header value set in the first line of the CSV file.
        Map(m => m.ID).Name("id");
        Map(m => m.Name).Name("name");
        Map(m => m.Lastname).Name("lastname");
        Map(m => m.Phone).Name("phone");
        Map(m => m.Mail).Name("mail");
        Map(m => m.Website).Name("website");
    }
}
```

Some more details in an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9085399/5894241).