# Escape special characters while loading into csv using c#

Tags: c#

I have a c# application which exports the data from SQL server to CSV. During one such export the data from the table is split into multiple columns due to the presence of certain special characters.

How can I load the data without losing the special characters and without splitting the column data into several columns?

Below is the code sample that is not working fine.

```
sw.Write( string.Format("\""+column.ToString()+"\""));
```

where column value is:

> Need to add  "ABCD, LMSW @ 123-456-789" and  J Yu, PhD @ 123-456-789"  to OFFICE INFORMATION box on the right side of the web page:  https://xyz.abc.yz.edu/

Comment: Just use a CSV parsing library.  They have already solved this problem better than you will.

Comment: could you give me an example please

Comment: Just google C# CSV parsing libraries

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing CSV files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081418/).

Comment: Guys , I am trying to load the data into the csv from SQL Server table using the C# application. The links that has been provided as duplicate are the other way around

Comment: The libraries mentioned can also create CSV files from SQL data using a C# application.