# CSV Parser, how to auto discover col names & types

Tags: csv, reflection, filehelpers, csvhelper

I am loading CVS files for data import. The files come from various sources *so the header names and location are often changing.* I searched and found helpful libs like [CsvHelper & FileHelpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081418/parsing-csv-files-in-c-with-header)

**Question**: either using FileHelper.net or CsvHelper, **how do we extract both the Header names & the `Column datatype`?** so that I can create a drop for each col, to *map* between .NET type <==> to a SQL type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read in the first line of the file with, say,

```
string headers = File.ReadLines("MyFile.txt").First();
```

And then use a [class builder](https://www.filehelpers.net/docs/html/N_FileHelpers_Dynamic.htm) to build whatever CSV spec you need.

```
DelimitedClassBuilder cb = new DelimitedClassBuilder("MyProduct", delimiter: ",");

cb.AddField("Name", typeof(string));
cb.LastField.TrimMode = TrimMode.Both;

cb.AddField("Description", typeof(string));
cb.LastField.FieldQuoted = true;
cb.LastField.QuoteChar = '"';
cb.LastField.QuoteMode = QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth;

// etc... e.g., add a date field
cb.AddField("SomeDate", typeof(DateTime));

engine = new FileHelperEngine(cb.CreateRecordClass());

DataTable dt = engine.ReadFileAsDT("test.txt");
```

Comment: thanks, I see your suggestion to make it as typeof string, I may follow this suggestion. My concern is that, I would _loose date and number cols like price/cost_. Also, _how to go about getting the headers in the first row?_

Comment: Get the headers with `File.ReadLines("MyFile.txt").First();`

Comment: Then iterate through those headers and build your record class as shown in the sample code. You can specify any type for each column. Notice the _SomeDate_ field is being created with `typeof(DateTime)`.

Comment: yes, but how would i know during coding time if that field was datetime...? because here it assumes i know some col x to be of `typeof(DateTime)` ... but I dont. Header- BTW I get it now, with the header. After calling first will the pointer/cursor move to the second row?

Comment: FileHelpers does not magically know what type of data a column contains. You have to tell it.

Comment: You could assume everything is `typeof(string)` and then write a routine to detect and convert a column to something more specific.