# How would i Store Part of someting.split() into it's own array?

Tags: c#

I have this code that reads a csv file and on every line it uses `line.split(',')` to sort each part of one line into `values`, a string array.

How would I then put "values[1]" into it's own array?

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string line;
    string[] countrys;

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Countries_database.csv"))
    {
        try
        {
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                var values = line.Split(',');
                Console.WriteLine(values[1]);
            }
            countrys = values[1];
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read {0}", ex);
        }

    }
}
```

The `countrys = values[1];` does not work but it just shows what I am aiming to do.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Think you'll need to explain what you are expecting a bit more.. Values[1] will be a `string`, are you wanting 1 string value in a random array? are you wanting value 1 from each line in the same array?

Comment: Aren't you doing that already with `countrys = values[1];`?

Comment: Are you trying to parse a CSV file? `line.Split(',')` [doesn't do that](http://www.secretgeek.net/csv_trouble) but there are plenty of [tools available that do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081418/).

Comment: you could either initialize a new array with only one member or you could further split the string into another array.  But without knowing what you're trying to do i can't say which.    var countrys = values.Split(','); << this will split your values into it's own array  OR string[] countrys = new string[] { values };  << this will place your values string at position 0 in a new array.

Answer (score 2):

How about a list?  That way, you don't have to worry about the indexing / sizing.

```
List<string> countries = new List<string>();
...//read stuff
countries.Add(values[1]); //add the string to the list
```

Comment: I like lists sooo much more than arrays, personally.  A lot easier to use

Answer (score 2):

Your `values` array object is out of scope to assign it to `countrys` - i.e. where you do:

`countrys = values[1];`

Your `var values = line.Split(',');` will create `values` only in the scope of that iteration of your while loop. So you should ideally add it to a list that is declared outside of the while loop, or assign it once in the while loop and then break out of the while loop.

Something like this might work better:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string line;
    List<string> countrys = new List<string>();

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Countries_database.csv"))
    {
        try
        {
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                var values = line.Split(',');
                Console.WriteLine(values[1]);
                countrys.Add(values[1]);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read {0}", ex);
        }

    }
}
```