# Sorting CSV file by column using QuickSort c#

Tags: c#, csv, sorting, quicksort

I have a file called Item.csv file which has the following information:

```
categoryName, currentPrice, currencyId
Boots, 19.95, GBP
Thermometers,2.03,GBP
Garden Sheds,38.95,GBP
```

I want to sort the content by price by making use of QSortAlgorithm and save it as sortedItem.csv.
So far I can pull out the price column and sort it by making use of QSortAlgorithm but I don't know how to put it all together. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
List <double> priceList=new List<double>();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Items.csv"))
            {
                String line;

                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] parts = line.Split(',');
                    string price = parts[1]; 
                    if(price!="currentPrice")
                    priceList.Add(Convert.ToDouble(price));
                }
            }    
            double [] priceArray=new double[priceList.Count];
             priceArray=priceList.ToArray();
             QuickSort(ref priceArray);
             for(int i=0;i<priceArray.Length;i++)
             Console.WriteLine(priceArray[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could an object to bring all together. I also do not know your Quicksort algorithm, but the sort method of the List class seems to do a good job.

Here ist your code reworked with an object und sorting all by the price:

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Items.csv"))
{
    string line;

    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] parts = line.Split(',');
        string price = parts[1];
        if (price != "currentPrice")
            items.Add(new Item
            {
                CurrentPrice = Convert.ToDouble(price),
                CategoryName = parts[0],
                CurrencyId = parts[2]
            });
    }
}
foreach (Item item in items.OrderBy(i => i.CurrentPrice))
    Console.WriteLine(item.CategoryName + "," +
                      item.CurrentPrice + "," +
                      item.CurrencyId);

public class Item
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public double CurrentPrice { get; set; }
    public string CurrencyId { get; set; }
}
```

But you should consider using a CSV parser its a more cleaner approach.
Like the `TextFieldParser` described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20523165/11896942

Comment: thanks. Currently, my algorithm takes as an input an array and then sort that.https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29467/Quick-Sort-Without-Recursion