# C# csv to jaggedarray (How to return Columns)

Tags: c#

I have a csv file that I need to capture data from. I have code that I found on stack overflow that returns that csv data in the form of a jagged array, I have never worked with jagged arrays before and I'm having a tough time figuring out how to loop through the data.

My idea is to have a function that returns column data from the array

```
        public static string[][] retJaggedArray(int row, int column, string file)
        {
            string[][] m_Data = File
                .ReadLines(file)
                .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                .Select(line => line.Split(','))
                .ToArray();

            return m_Data;
        }

string[] data = retJaggedArray(23, 1, file); >> returns the column data
```

Please also let me know the conventions of dealing with a jagged array

Comment: By columns data, do you mean if there's a column X, return an array containing each row values of column X?

Comment: For parsing CSV files, use one of the existing [CSV parsing libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2081418/8967612) and don't reinvent the wheel. It's not as easy as it might seem.

Comment: Ill look into the link you gave, thanks man