# Really bad performance for large Lists of strings and .txt files

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, search, text-files

What you need to know:

My application uses a database for foods, which exists in a `.txt` file. Each food has about **170** datas (*2-3 digit numbers*) which are separated by **tabstops**, and each food is again separated by **\n**, so ***each line*** in this `.txt` file has the datas for ***1*** food.

The applications target platform is **Android**, it needs to work **offline** and I use **Unity** with **c#** for coding.

My 2 Problems are:

1. **Getting access to the `.txt` file**

As it is not possible for android applications to access a `.txt` file by

`$"{Application.DataPath}/textFileName.txt"`

I assigned the .txt file as a `TextAsset` (*name*: `txtFile`) in the **Inspector**. When the app gets started for the first time I load all the data of the `TextAsset` file into a `json` (*name*: `jsonStringList`), which contains a List of strings:

`for (int i = 0; i < amountOfLinesInTextFile; i++); { jsonStringList.Add(txtFile.text.Split('\n')[i]) }`

Technically that *does* work, but unfortunately the `txtFile` has a total of about **15000** lines, which makes it *really* slow (`Stopwatch` time for the `for-loop`: **≈750000 ms**, which is about **12.5 minutes**...)

Obviously it is not an option to let the user wait for that long when opening the app for the first time...

2. **Searching in that `jsonList`**

- In that app it is possible to make an own food by putting multiple foods together. To do that the user has to *search* for a **food** and can then press the **result** to add it.
- Currently I check in a `for-loop` if the input of the user-searchbar `InputField` (*name*: `searchbar`) matches a food of the `jsonStringList` and if that food is *not* already displayed.
- If *both* is true, I add the *name* of the food to a `List<string>` (*name*: `results`), which is what I use to display the matching foods. (As the datas (including the name) of the foods are separated by *tabstops* I use `.Split('\t')` to get the correct data for the name of the food)

  ```
    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfLinesInTextFile; i++)
    {   string name = jsonStringList[i].Split('\t')[nameIndex].ToLower();
        if (name.Equals(searchBar.text.ToLower()) && !results.Contains(name))
        {
            results.Add(name);
        }
    }
  ```

Again: That *technically* works, but it is also **too slow** (even tough it's *much* faster then **problem 1**)

(`Stopwatch` for the `for-loop`: **≈1600 ms**)

I'd be very happy for any help to improve the time of those two actions!
Maybe there is a whole different approach for handling such large .txt files, but every bit of decreasing the time would be helpful!

Comment: *txtFile.text.Split('\n')[i]* - thats enormous leakage, you split entire file 15000 times just to get one line

Comment: How can I replace that? For _File.ReadAllLines_ I would need a path to the .txt file but as the app is for android - and from what I read so far android includes the _.txt_ file in the _.apk_ of the app - I can't access it (or am I missing something?)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stringreader?view=net-6.0 for search use *Dictionary<string, YourTableRow>* with *StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase* comparer.

Comment: *or am I missing something?* - you're somehow getting access to the file contents currently; that's good - it's not the slow part. The slow part is how you're treating the file; you're using list for everything and splitting far too much. A massive part of the design of efficient programs is sensible data container choices. Read up on the differences between a List, Dictionary, HashSet, array, LinkedList, Stack and Queue so you're better equipped to choose appropriately. Your `results` should perhaps be a HashSet for example, if it has more than a low number of items

Comment: You need to do `var splitResult = txtFile.text.Split('\n')` ONCE and then do `jsonStringList.Add(splitResult[i])` inside the loop (though I'd say to just iterate over the result of split, and don't index).  I don't think that always came across from others.  You're reading the *entire* file equal to the number of lines it has. And since you had `amountOfLinesInTextFile` already, it means you already read it at least once for that too!

Comment: So I tried the first suggestion of @eocron ´s Answer and I already got the loading time down to 500 ms which is really amazing! I will try improving that more with the other suggestions, thank you all!!! (I will comment the final time it takes when I finished this part of the application & I would love to upvote your comments but I don't have enough points yet)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

15000 is not a big file, really. You just do too many unnecessary reading/transformations. You need to do it once, cache it (save in variable in your case), reuse it.

```
var foodIndex = txtFile
  .text
  .Split('\n')                //get rows
  .Select(x=> x.Split('\t'))  //get columns for each row
  .ToDictionary(x=> x[nameIndex], StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);   //build case-insensitive search index

var myFood = foodIndex["aPpLe"];
```

This produce `Dictionary<string, string[]>`

##### Better approach

Deserialize [CSV format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) (your file is obviously CSV table) into [POCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_CLR_object#:%7E:text=Plain%20Old%20CLR%20Object%20is,sometimes%20used%20is%20plain%20old%20.) row:

```
public class Food
{
   [DataMember(Order=1)] //here is your nameIndex
   public string Name {get;set;}
   [DataMember(Order=2)]
   public int Amount {get;set;}
   //...
}

var foodIndex = SomeCSVParse<Food>(txtFile.text)
  .ToDictionary(x=> x.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

var myFood = foodIndex["aPpLe"];
```

This produce `Dictionary<string, Food>` search index, which look better, easier to use.

This way all conversion from string to int/double/datetime/etc, order of columns, separators (comma, tab, whitespace), cultures (in case there is float/double), efficient reading, headers, etc can be just ditched to 3rd party framework. Someone did this here - [Parsing CSV files in C#, with header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081418/parsing-csv-files-in-c-with-header)

There is also plethora of frameworks on nuget, just pick whatever is  smaller/popular or copypaste from sources - https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=CSV

And read more about data structures in C# - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/