# How to fix regex for parsing CSV data to work with empty substrings

Tags: .net, regex

How to change the following regex:

`(?:(^|,)(?<quote>"|)(?<value>.*?)(\k<quote>)(?=(,|$)))`

which works with:
`1,1,-1` ... I get `"1","1","-1"`

and works with:
`"1","1","-1"` ... I get `"1","1","-1"`

---

but it doesn't work as expected when one or more or the substrings are empty:

`,1,-1` ...in such case I need to get: `"", "1", "1"`

`,"1","-1"` ...in such case I need to get: `"", "1", "1"`

`,"1",` ...in such case I need to get: `"", "1", ""`

`,,` ...in such case I need to get: `"","",""`

Is that possible?

Comment: Try `(?<=,|^)(?<quote>"?)(?<value>.*?)\k<quote>(?=,|$)`

Comment: If you're trying to parse CSV files, you might want to consider [using a CSV parser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2081418/87698) instead of a regular expression. There are a lot of edge cases (values contain doubled quotes, value contain line breaks, etc.), and you want to avoid re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<=,|^)(?<quote>"?)(?<value>.*?)\k<quote>(?=,|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GGVcLF/1).

*Details*:

- `(?<=,|^)` - start of string or a location right after a comma
- `(?<quote>"?)` - an optional double quote captured into Group "quote"
- `(?<value>.*?)` - Group "value": any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\k<quote>` - same char as in Group "quote"
- `(?=,|$)` - a location right before a comma or end of string.