# What is the good way to read data from CSV and converting them to JSON?

Tags: json, powershell, performance, csv, ip2location

I am trying to read the data from CSV file which has 2200000 records using PowerShell and storing each record in JSON file, but this takes almost 12 hours.

**Sample CSV Data:**

We will only concern about the 1st column value's.

[image]

**Code:**

```
function Read-IPData
{
    $dbFilePath = Get-ChildItem -Path $rootDir -Filter "IP2*.CSV" | ForEach-Object{ $_.FullName }
    Write-Host "file path - $dbFilePath"

    Write-Host "Reading..."
    $data = Get-Content -Path $dbFilePath | Select-Object -Skip 1
    Write-Host "Reading data finished"

    $count = $data.Count
    Write-host "Total $count records found"

    return $data
}

function Convert-NumbetToIP
{
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$number
    )

    try
    {    
        $w = [int64]($number/16777216)%256
        $x = [int64]($number/65536)%256
        $y = [int64]($number/256)%256
        $z = [int64]$number%256

        $ipAddress = "$w.$x.$y.$z"
        Write-Host "IP Address - $ipAddress"

        return $ipAddress
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "$_"
        continue
    }
}

Write-Host "Getting IP Addresses from $dbFileName"
$data = Read-IPData

Write-Host "Checking whether output.json file exist, if not create"
$outputFile = Join-Path -Path $rootDir -ChildPath "output.json"

if(!(Test-Path $outputFile))
{
    Write-Host "$outputFile doestnot exist, creating..."
    New-Item -Path $outputFile -type "file"
}

foreach($item in $data)
{
    $row = $item -split ","
    $ipNumber = $row[0].trim('"')

    Write-Host "Converting $ipNumber to ipaddress"
    $toIpAddress = Convert-NumbetToIP -number $ipNumber

    Write-Host "Preparing document JSON"
    $object = [PSCustomObject]@{
        "ip-address" = $toIpAddress
        "is-vpn" = "true"
        "@timestamp" = (Get-Date).ToString("o")
    }

    $document = $object | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 100
    Write-Host "Adding document - $document"
    Add-Content -Path $outputFile $document
}
```

Could you please help optimize the code or is there a better way to do it. or is there a way like multi-threading.

Comment: Some ways to optimize CSV-to-JSON performance can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73517884/7571258

Comment: Are you hitting the `catch` block in `Convert-NumbetToIP` many times or almost never or never? The main issue with your code is `Add-Content`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Never hitting the catch block but kept so that if anything goes wrong with that record, it will skip and move on.

Comment: Your code will calculate wrong IP addresses every now and then, because of rounding errors. This is why you should use `-shr` (bitshift Shift-Right) on the **UNSigned** [UInt32] number value, not a **Signed** [Int64]. From your [link](https://www.ip2location.com/faqs#technical), the best comparison with how to do it in PowerShell is the code in `C` example. cc @zett42

Comment: @zett42 if( ($numberInt -ge 0) -and ($numberInt -le 0xFFFFFFFFl) ) will work similar to c example.

Comment: This is just a check to make sure that no exception is thrown if the input number is invalid, because exception processing is relatively slow. It has nothing to do with the C example.

Comment: @zett42 it's fantastic working fine just took 15 minutes to run.

Comment: @zett42 is there a way I can create multiple json file having 50 records per file, because posting whole file is giving an error via REST call.

Comment: @NaveenKumar This shouldn't be too difficult, but is better asked as a new question.

Comment: @zett42 Yes I have done that but creating and posting is still taking too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible optimization:

```sh
function Get-IPDataPath
{
    $dbFilePath = Get-ChildItem -Path $rootDir -Filter "IP2*.CSV" | ForEach-Object FullName | Select-Object -First 1
    Write-Host "file path - $dbFilePath"
    $dbFilePath  # implicit output
}

function Convert-NumberToIP
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$number
    )

    [Int64] $numberInt = 0
    if( [Int64]::TryParse( $number, [ref] $numberInt ) ) {
        if( ($numberInt -ge 0) -and ($numberInt -le 0xFFFFFFFFl) ) {
            # Convert to IP address like '192.168.23.42'
            ([IPAddress] $numberInt).ToString()
        }
    }
    # In case TryParse() returns $false or the number is out of range for an IPv4 address, 
    # the output of this function will be empty, which converts to $false in a boolean context.
}

$dbFilePath = Get-IPDataPath
$outputFile = Join-Path -Path $rootDir -ChildPath "output.json"

Write-Host "Converting CSV file $dbFilePath to $outputFile"

$object = [PSCustomObject]@{
    'ip-address' = ''
    'is-vpn' = 'true'
    '@timestamp' = ''
}

# Enclose foreach loop in a script block to be able to pipe its output to Set-Content
& {
    foreach( $item in [Linq.Enumerable]::Skip( [IO.File]::ReadLines( $dbFilePath ), 1 ) )
    {
        $row = $item -split ','
        $ipNumber = $row[0].trim('"')

        if( $ip = Convert-NumberToIP -number $ipNumber ) 
        {
            $object.'ip-address' = $ip
            $object.'@timestamp' = (Get-Date).ToString('o')

            # Implicit output
            $object | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 100
        }

    }
} | Set-Content -Path $outputFile
```

**Remarks for improving performance:**

- Avoid `Get-Content`, especially for line-by-line processing it tends to be slow. A much faster alternative is the [`File.ReadLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=net-7.0) method. To skip the header line, use the `Linq.Enumerable.Skip()` method.
- There is no need to read the whole CSV into memory first. Using `ReadLines` in a `foreach` loop does lazy enumeration, i. e. it reads only one line per loop iteration. This works because it returns an *enumerator* instead of a  collection of lines.
- Avoid `try` and `catch` if exceptions occur often, because the "exceptional" code path is very slow. Instead use `Int64.TryParse()` which returns a `boolean` indicating successful conversion.
- Instead of "manually" converting the IP number to bytes, use the [`IPAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress?view=net-7.0) class which has a constructor that takes an integer number. Use its method `.GetAddressBytes()` to get an array of bytes in network (big-endian) order. Finally use the PowerShell `-join` operator to create a string of the expected format.
- Don't allocate a `[pscustomobject]` for each row, which has some overhead. Create it once before the loop and inside the loop only assign the values.
- Avoid `Write-Host` (or any output to the console) within inner loops.

**Unrelated to performance:**

- I've removed the `New-Item` call to create the output file, which isn't necessary because `Set-Content` automatically creates the file if it doesn't exist.
- Note that the output is in [NDJSON format](https://github.com/ndjson/ndjson-spec), where *each line is like a JSON file*. In case you actually want this to be a *regular JSON file*, enclose the output in `[ ]` and insert a comma `,` between each row.

---

Modified processing loop to **write a regular JSON file** instead of NDJSON file:

```sh
& {
    '[' # begin array
    $first = $true

    foreach( $item in [Linq.Enumerable]::Skip( [IO.File]::ReadLines( $dbFilePath ), 1 ) )
    {
        $row = $item -split ','
        $ipNumber = $row[0].trim('"')

        if( $ip = Convert-NumberToIP -number $ipNumber ) 
        {
            $object.'ip-address' = $ip
            $object.'@timestamp' = (Get-Date).ToString('o')
        
            $row = $object | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 100

            # write array element delimiter if necessary
            if( $first ) { $row; $first = $false } else { ",$row" } 
        }

    }
    ']'  # end array
} | Set-Content -Path $outputFile
```

Comment: thanks I have checked but the output from Convert-NumberToIP is different from the what method I have used tried with "16778241". It's provided in documentation https://www.ip2location.com/faqs#technical

Comment: @NaveenKumar I've simplified IP adress conversion, please try new code.

Comment: is it possible to create 4 different files at the time of set-content in above code, so than I can store data in 4 different files 500000 records in each file instead of 1 big file.

Comment: Hi @zett42 how to use Convert-NumbetToIP function to convert decimal to IPV6

Comment: @NaveenKumar It looks like you need to convert number to byte array and then convert to `IPAddress`.

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize the function Convert-NumberToIP like below:

```
function Convert-NumberToIP {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][uint32]$number
    )

    # either do the math yourself like this:

    # $w = ($number -shr 24) -band 255
    # $x = ($number -shr 16) -band 255
    # $y = ($number -shr 8) -band 255
    # $z = $number -band 255
    # '{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}' -f $w, $x, $y, $z  # output the dotted IP string

    # or use .Net:
    $n = ([IPAddress]$number).GetAddressBytes()
    [array]::Reverse($n)
    ([IPAddress]$n).IPAddressToString
}
```